# hey how do you get the r,g,b value of blue and green and replace them using PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

.
hey how do you get the r,g,b value of blue and green and replace them using PIL

Comment: Get the RGB of blue and green *where* in your image? And replace them with *what*? Please also show your input image and expected result - along with your best attempt at coding it yourself. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to access the pixel values would be to use .load() on your image.

```
    pixels = image.load()

    for x in range(image.size[0]):
        for y in range(image.size[1]):

            pixels[x, y][1] = 0 # Change green value
            pixels[x, y][2] = 0 # Change blue value
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have to use PIL, but with opencv you can easily change the channels for your whole picture without the need for a for loop (and hence increase performance).

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('filename')
```

Each pixel `im[x,y]` has a tuple (when an RGB image is read) with the different channels. The colors are: BGR (*not RGB*).
If you want your image in RGB you can do `im = im[...,::-1]`.

For example if I want to set the blue channel to zero:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('filename')
# Note it is BGR, thus blue = 0
im[:,:,0] = 0
```

This shows that this can be done per pixel, per row or per columns or other fancy ways when manipulating arrays.